# Qual o Local adequado para se alocar as bibliotecas Javascript e CSS no CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3

Qual o Local adequado para se alocar as bibliotecas e plugins `Javascript` e `CSS` no CakePHP 3, pois houve um grande mudança na estrutura de diretórios desta versão para anterior.

Todos os arquivos `.js` e `.css` tem um local especifico e separados.

Todas as chamadas a arquivos são feitas desta forma ():

```
<?= $this->Html->css('style.css') ?>
<?= $this->Html->script('main.js',['defer' => true]) ?>
```

Logo é possível notar que há presunção do diretório onde os arquivos estão.

Estrutura de diretórios (Tirei prints para verem 100% a estrutura e o que tem dentro de cada):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS:** Plugins e Bibliotecas como Jquery, Jquery-ui e Bootstrap possuem pastas e subpastas, arquivos de fontes, icones, imagens, javascript e css.

Comment: Geralmente o front-end vai no public, www, webroot e assim vai.

Comment: @gmsantos e como ficaria as referencias?

Comment: O cakephp faz isso reescrevendo pelo `.htaccess`. Provavelmente, `css/default.css` apontaria para `app/webroot/css/default.css`

Comment: @ricardo não conheço os métodos `Html->css() ` do cake, quando estiver com um tempinho aqui vou pesquisar nos docs. O que eu faço é mapear no apache a pasta webroot como root e nos arquivos referenciar o caminho relativo, que seria css/default.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve colocar na pasta `webroot` da sua aplicação, levando em consideração que o caminho apontado para o `css` ou `js` seria declarado sem o "webroot"

Exemplo:

No html `css/default.css` aponta para o diretório `webroot/css/default.css`

Veja o código .htaccess do Cakephp 3, para ter mais certeza disso:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/.htaccess

Comment: e como ficaria a declaração por exemplo: <?= $this->Html->css('style.css') ?> esta aponta para um arquivo solto dentro da pasta css que esta dentro do webroot, como ficaria para lingar um css da lib bootstrap?